# How to install Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on a Windows 7 computer, I'm the admin. I keep searching for a guide or tutorial to help, but nothing has popped up.

I installed Ruby 2.0 on my computer last night, then realized that 4.0 has come. Do I need to uninstall it for Rails to work? I'm relatively new to this and am confused. Any links to anything would surely help.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Ruby != Rails.  Ruby's (the programming language) current version is 2.0, while Rails (the application framework) is 4.something.  From the command line, `gem install rails`

Comment: Oh okay, this worked out! I had the right ones downloaded, thank you very much. Do I do anything else after in cmd after rails is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 is the most recent version of Ruby, a programming language. Rails 4.0 is the most recent version of Rails, a web app framework for Ruby which is actually designed with Ruby 2.0 in mind. You install Rails 4.0 [just like every other version of Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/download): `gem install rails`.